# presentModalViewController and initWithRootViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController class named **UserInfoViewController**,  when it will show up, the parentViewControoler use code like this:

```
    UserInfoViewController *rvc = [[UserInfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserInfoViewController" bundle:nil];
    rvc.user = user;
    UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rvc];
    nc.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    [self presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];
    [rvc release];
    [nc release];
```

Sometimes UserInfoViewController will push or present another  view controller, so the stack should be like :

```
Root VC
     |
     A (push)
     |
     | - B (present)
           |
           |-- C (push)
                 |
                 |- D (push)
                     |
                     |- E (present)
```

B, E is class of **UserInfoViewController**.

The problem is,  when on view controller E, I want to close all viewcontrollers and return to **Root VC** , but I can't deal with them at once.

I tried **popToRootViewControllerAnimated**, **dismissModalViewControllerAnimated**, **setViewControllers**, but none of them working.

I also put a notification listener in **B E**, when need to return Root VC, just post that notification, and in the listener selector, do:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

then **C D**  is closed, but  ** B E **  still there.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

Just don't think about pop or dismiss it, let it go whit navigationController's dealloc action.

so, when you want to remove all view controllers from screen, in app delegate:

```
    self.window.rootViewController = nil;
```

and when you need to showing something again :

```
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

That's it.